# Laravel tinker display a #706 when create a object on model

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to create an object on tinker like this:

```
$user = new App\User;
```

It outputs the result like this:

[image]

I am referencing Laravel cast tutorials where this `$user = new App\User;` piece of code displays the table structure and its relationship.

But if I fetch a result:

[image]

This is what he get when call a method on tinker
[image]

What is the reason?

Comment: The {#704} is some sort of memory key. Don't pay any attention to that. The id is what really matters.

Comment: k, but  why don't outputs the table structure and its relational views

Comment: if i want to check the table structre and its relational view how to get with the tinker

Comment: This is not the intended behaviour of tinker. I added an answer, maybe you can understand it better..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a misconception. From what I'm seeing, `tinker` is a command to interact with your application. A simple REPL (Read Eval Print Loop) tool to run your application on the command-line.

You're doing the following:

```
$user = App\User::first();
```

Well, that is an Eloquent method you are calling, which consults the database, gets the first user and outputs it (in this case that is the command line).

To answer your question: you cannot see the database structure on this command line, except if there is any code in your application to output this.

Why aren't you consulting the datastore your connecting to (probably one of these: Mysql, in-memory, SQLite)?

A good place to start is to look at your migrations. You can also, if you're using Mysql, download Mysql workbench.

Comment: thank you for explanation . of course it is my misunderstanding. but i have updated a new image(3rd image), what he get as the output when he create a object on tinker... but i don't get this..

Answer (score 1):

This is the indeed behavior. When you type

```
$user = new App\User;
```

you are instantiating the User model so you can set its name and other values and save it to db, so at first nothing should apear only the class you just instantiated.

and when you type

```
App\User::first();
```

it returns the first row of the db with its structure and values, but only if you have at least one row in db, case else it would return just  `null`.

> Oh, and by the way the **#706** its just a random id laravel and tinker uses, nothing to worry about, mine was **#689**.

Comment: but according to the Laravel cast tutorial its outputs the table structure.

Comment: if i want to check the table structure and its relational view how to get with the tinker